# Eliminar un mensaje con Message.id discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

Quiero crear un comando con el bot donde le pase el id de dicho mensaje y lo borre pero no logro que funcione

```
from discord.ext import commands 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=main.check_config("prefix"), description=main.check_config("description"), intents=intents, help_command=None)

@bot.command()
async def delete_message(ctx, text: str):
    """_summary_

    Args:
        ctx (_type_): contexto
        text (str): donde el id_message se guardara
    """
    if ctx.message.author == main.bot_owner:
        message = ctx.text
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("borrado")
```

Ejemplos de interacción:

bot_owner: !delete_message 101010101010101

bot: borrado

Comment: Intentaste con [ctx.fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.fetch_message). Justamente eso crea un objeto message a partir de la id de un mensaje. Peeeero el id debe ser un número, no una cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Pasos:

1. Tienes que obtener el identificador del mensaje a borrar, este se encuentra almacenado en el parámetro `text`.
2. Puedes hacer uso de la función [`ctx.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20context#discord.ext.commands.Context.fetch_message) para obtener el [`mensaje`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message) a borrar a partir del identificador.
3. Una vez has recuperado el `mensaje`, puedes borrarlo con la función [`message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.delete).

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.command(name="delete_message")
async def delete_message(ctx : commands.Context, text : str):

  if ctx.author == bot.user:

    m = await ctx.fetch_message(int(text))
    await m.delete()
    await ctx.send("Borrado")
```

---

El comando es aún muy mejorable ya que solo contempla el caso en el que todo funciona bien. Casos adicionales que podrías contemplar:

1. Un usuario no autorizado usa el comando: Podrías añadir un `else` enviando un mensaje que informe al usuario que no está autorizado.
2. El valor del parámetro `text` puede no ser un identificador: Deberías añadir comprobaciones adicionales (que solo se pase una palabra, que la palabra sea un número, etc.).
3. Es posible que `ctx.fetch_message()` no recupere el mensaje: [Captura las excepciones](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20context#discord.ext.commands.Context.fetch_message).
4. Es posible que `m.delete()` no borre el mensaje: [Captura las excepciones](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.delete).

Comment: También te faltaba añadir el [message_content intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.message_content), en el código se ve cómo. En caso de que salte un error/warning avisándote de que no activaste dicho intent desde el developer portal, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74045886/20214407) tienes un tutorial de como hacerlo (está en inglés, pero es muy simple)